# How to pull Gowalla Json feed with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I've tried to use this method, but it doesn't display anything in HTML page:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("http://gowalla.com/api/explorer#/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.spots, function (i, spot) {
    $("<img/>").attr("src", spot._image_url_200).appendTo("#images");
    });

    $("#title").html(data.total_pages);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work, but unfortunaly you can't use JSONP with Gowalla, just for a simple fact

> Gowalla doesn't support wrapping the JSON in a callback

btw, Foursquare has the same problem... err, well we do have the problem, not them specifically :(

and by the way, the correct URL to use would be:

```
http://api.gowalla.com/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50"
```

as you can check by [their api tool](http://gowalla.com/api/explorer#/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50), **you will get a HTTP 404** as that's the way [they give you the error](http://gowalla.com/api/docs#responses).